# Unable to connect to Cassandra remotely using DataStax Python driver

Tags: python, cassandra, database-connection, datastax

I'm having trouble connecting to Cassandra (running on an EC2 node) remotely (from my laptop). When I use the DataStax Python driver for Cassandra:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['10.X.X.X'], port=9042)
cluster.connect()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-23-dc85f20fd4f5>", line 1, in <module>
    session = cluster.connect()
  File "/Users/user/virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 755, in connect
    self.control_connection.connect()
  File "/Users/user/virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1868, in connect
    self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())
  File "/Users/user/virtualenvs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1903, in _reconnect_internal
    raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.X.X.X': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None',)})
```

But Cassandra is running because `nodetool status` gives me:

```
UN 127.0.0.1 124.18 KB 256 100.0% 4d973e17-ae08-3aa1-81d2-605b92753694 rack1
```

Cassandra also seems to be listening on port 9042:

```
netstat -nltp | grep 9042

tcp6       0      0 0.0.0.0:9042            :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

And I can telnet from my laptop to Cassandra:

```
$ telnet 10.X.X.X 9042
Trying 10.X.X.X...
Connected to ip-10-X-X-X.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Relevant highlights from my cassandra.yaml:

```
start_native_transport: true
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.X.X.X
```

`/var/log/cassandra/system.log` shows nothing useful.

*edit*:
I can also connect to Cassandra using `cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042` on the server, and `cqlsh 10.X.X.X 9042` from my laptop without any problems.

---

**Solution**

Looks like the one place where I tested my script (a Python console inside PyCharm) is, for some reason, the only place where my script does not work. No problems running as a script in PyCharm or in Python/iPython interactive mode. I will leave the question, as it contains a fairly complete checklist for Python-to-Cassandra connection troubleshooting.

Comment: Does 'nodetool status' show UN?

Comment: @phact: Yes, it does:
`UN  127.0.0.1  124.18 KB  256     100.0%            4d973e17-ae08-3aa1-81d2-605b92753694  rack1`

Comment: Hm can you turn on logging at the driver

Comment: This might be the cause of the problem in PyCharm: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-289

Comment: I put the machine ip instead of localhost in rcp_address; and then noticed the yaml snippet here;

Comment: I have the same issue, connecting using cqlsh works, but pytest, tox, interactive mode will fail (cannot connect), while running a separate script works... Using driver -v 3.7.1, python 3.4.4.

Answer (score 3):

Such exception can be thrown if a [control connection timeout](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Cluster.control_connection_timeout) was exceeded. Try to increase it or set it to `None` to completely disable this timeout. For example:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'], control_connection_timeout=10,  port=9042)
cluster.connect()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple debug method for you: 
 On another machine which has cassandra installed, using cassandra cli command "cqlsh 10.X.X.X" to connect the remote cassandra server. If failed , then you should modify cassandra configuration file for the cassandra remote mode.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I can use CQL both on the server and from my laptop. Something must be off on the driver side.

Comment: @Def_Os My cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042 is working but cqlsh 192.168.X.X 9042 is not working on server even. I have changed these values in yaml file. start_native_transport: true
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
rpc_port: 9160
broadcast_rpc_address: 192.168.X.X