# I can't connect to Cassandra with DataStax Python driver

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm having trouble connecting to Cassandra (running on an EC2 node) **locally** with DataStax Python driver for Cassandra: (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608548/unable-to-connect-to-cassandra-remotely-using-datastax-python-driver))

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'], port=9042)
cluster.connect()
```

I get:

```
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection (5 seconds), last_host=None',)})
```

The same if i run:

```
cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'], port=9160)
cluster.connect()
```

The service seems to listen in the correct port:

netstat -nltp | grep 9042
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          :::*                    LISTEN      -

Also the command `cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042` work perfectly.

I have the default settings on file `cassandra.yaml`:

```
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160
```

I also tried to change the rpc_address with the PRIVATE_IP of my ec2 instance but nothing changed.

I don't use PyCharm, I use the interactive console of python on my instance.

Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by reinstalling cassandra using the [DataStax Community AMI](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/install/installAMI.html) on Amazon AWS. Probably was a problem of versions of Cassandra and Datastax python driver.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44498472/469154) as well:

I've learned that the `gevent` module interferes with the `cassandra-driver`

- cassandra-driver (3.10)
- gevent (1.1.1)

Uninstalling gevent solved the problem for me

```
pip uninstall gevent
```